# How to properly use the same Class in Anglular and NodeJs server with Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have the following file that I called models.ts

```
import {BusStage} from "./busStage";

export class BusRoute {
    name: string;
    origin_direction_1: string;
    origin_direction_2: string;
    stops: number;
    id: string;
    meta: object;
    path: Direction;
    prev: string;
    next: string;
    arrival: Arrival;
}
export class Arrival {
    busstop_id: string;
    busstop_name: string;
    arrival_in: string;
    bus_left: string;
    all_arrivals: ArrivalSchedule[];
}
export class ArrivalSchedule{
    minutesLeft: string;
    arrivalTime: string;
    arrivalStatus:string;
}
export class Direction {
    direction1: BusStage[];
    direction2: BusStage[];
    direction3: BusStage[];
}
```

My back end is NodeJs that supports Typescript and it serves my frontend which is Angular as static files. My server also exposes an API that allow both ends to communicate json request and responses. Now I want to use the same `models.ts` file in both frontend and backend without having to duplicate the file and manually synchronizing everytime I make a change.

What is the correct way to do that? I was thinking of writing a script that watches any file change and copying it in both back end and front end folder everytime there is a change. However, I see it more as a workaround than a solution. Is what I am trying to achieve possible ?

Here is my folder structure:

```
|models.ts
   |_frontend/
      |_src
      |_package.json
      |_tsconfig.json
      |_...

   |_backend/
      |_src
          |_server.ts
      |_dist/
      |_package.json
      |_tsconfig.json
      |_...
```

Comment: I don't like to mess Client vs Server code. When you say " without having to duplicate" what means that (you wanna save disk space)? It is much better to make independent parts. It is possible, like @M U says put common methods intro root file folder...

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not write any watchers! :)
2. Yarn workspaces come to help.
3. Make the root project which will have package JSON only to specify the workspaces.
4. Put backend and frontend in separate folders.
5. Put tsconfig.base (or something like this) in the root level, while adding `"baseUrl": ".",` to it, which will let you to use one hoisted node_modules in the top level and all modules will be properly resolved.
6. Create folder e.g. `libs` or `types` and add it to the workspaces.
7. Create a package, either in top folder types or in some nested folder called like @your-project/types
8. Add this package to dev deps of your frontend and backend.
9. Now, you can use types,interfaces or classes between the front/back-ends and you have it synchronized all the time at no cost.

I hope it is what you were looking for.